# How can add custom html tag using tcPdf?

Tags: php, tcpdf

I have an HTML file.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <sign1 style="border: 3px red solid;padding: 10px 100px;"></sign1>
    <sign2 id="sellersign" style="border: 3px red solid;padding: 10px 100px;"></sign2 >
  </body>
</html>
```

When I am generating a pdf using **TCPDF** then the `<sign1>` and `<sign2>` tags did not display in pdf, So how can add custom HTML tags using the **TCPDF**?

PHP code is here:

```
    $path = __DIR__;
    $html=$path."/htmlFile.html"

    require_once $path . './vendor/autoload.php';
    $pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

    // set document information
    $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
    $pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
    $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 006');
    $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
    $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

    // add a page
    $pdf->AddPage();

    // output the HTML content
    $pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');

    $pdf->Output($path.'/pdfFiles/tcPdf.pdf', 'F');
```

Or Any other PHP library to allow custom tag and digital signature for PDF

Comment: the only tags displayed are the same managed by the library, you cannot use not standard tags

Comment: No application will process non-standard HTML tags. You will need to load your file, do a search/replace of the non-standard code and convert them to standard HTML.

Comment: @all Any other PHP library to allow custom tag and digital signature for PDF.